# Zlib Inflate Example

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

I wanted to ask for an example of Zlib Inflate/Deflate code for Delphi or Pascal as throughout the web I can't find it...Everywhere its in C/C++...

I went though all of the available resources and was able to find this out:

```
procedure ZDecompress(const inBuffer: Pointer; inSize: Integer;
  out outBuffer: Pointer; out outSize: Integer; outEstimate: Integer);
var
  zstream: TZStreamRec;
  delta: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(zstream, SizeOf(TZStreamRec), 0);

  delta := (inSize + 255) and not 255;

  if outEstimate = 0 then outSize := delta
  else outSize := outEstimate;

  GetMem(outBuffer, outSize);

  try
    zstream.next_in := inBuffer;
    zstream.avail_in := inSize;
    zstream.next_out := outBuffer;
    zstream.avail_out := outSize;

    ZDecompressCheck(InflateInit(zstream));

    try
      while ZDecompressCheck(inflate(zstream, Z_NO_FLUSH)) <> Z_STREAM_END do
      begin
        Inc(outSize, delta);
        ReallocMem(outBuffer, outSize);

        zstream.next_out := PChar(Integer(outBuffer) + zstream.total_out);
        zstream.avail_out := delta;
      end;
    finally
      ZDecompressCheck(inflateEnd(zstream));
    end;

    ReallocMem(outBuffer, zstream.total_out);
    outSize := zstream.total_out;
  except
    FreeMem(outBuffer);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

I assume this procedure is for Inflating. Any suggested codes & procedures by you masters for the same purpose???

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use these procedures, not TCompressionStream / TDecompressionStream? They are much easier to work with.

Comment: I just wanna learn the Inflate/Deflate procedures...If TCompressionStream / TDecompressionStream can perform the work, then I'm way too happy with it too ^_^

Comment: This question is off topic as described by the articles in the [help]. You need to use websearch.

Comment: Respected sir...As I mentioned in my main post...I wasn't able to find anything on WWW...All examples were in C++...Please, I need this thing...

Comment: We've closed the question and explained why. You should heed the advice in the close notice above. Please do so.

Comment: @Zenith suppose you want to compress file. It can be done in 3 lines of code: fileIn: = TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenWrite); fileOut: = TFileStream.Create(FileName+'.zlib', fmCreate); ZCompressStream(fileIn, fileOut);   That's it. Then you should free both file streams and even better, use try..finally blocks so they are freed even if some error occured, but generally, it's very easy. You can use another types of streams, what exactly do you need?

Comment: @Zenith I think that's exact point you can't find anything: unlike 'raw' zlib library in C++ where you have to initialize buffer, send data in and out and check return values, here it's so simple that you only have to have some little experience with delphi TStream to use these procedures.

Comment: Search for "paszlib", Free Pascal ships with it default, and its T(DE)compressionstream's are based on it

Comment: Thanks for your comments masters...I was basically searching for an Inflate & Deflate procedure, as I wanted to add it in my Project...I'm making a compressor...Inflating then compressing can provide me better ratio...

Comment: The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.ZLib.inflate) for inflate says: "For internal use only. -- Do not use this function. It is for internal use only. For more information, see the original documentation provided by ZLib library."

Answer (score 1):

uses ,system.ZLib;

```
     TWadItem = Class
                 private


                      _UncompressedData:TMemoryStream;
                      _CompressedData:TMemoryStream;

                  public

                  public

                  Procedure Pack;
                  procedure unpack;
...

procedure TWadItem.Pack;
var
    lz:TZCompressionStream;
begin
    if _CompressedData<>nil then exit;
    if _UnCompressedData=nil then exit;
    if _Uncompresseddata.Size<1 then exit;
    _CompressedData:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    _UnCompressedData.Seek(0,0);


    lz:=TZCompressionStream.Create(TCompressionLevel.clMax,_CompressedData);
    lz.CopyFrom(_UnCompressedData,_UnCOmpressedData.Size);
    LZ.Free;
    _UnCompressedData.free;
    _UnCompressedData:=NIL;

end;
procedure TWadItem.unpack;
var
    lz:TZDeCompressionStream;
    buff:TBytes;
begin
    if _UnCompressedData<>nil then exit;
    if _CompressedData=nil then exit;

    _UnCompressedData:=TMemoryStream.Create;

    lz:=TZDeCompressionStream.Create(_CompressedData);
    _unCompressedData.CopyFrom(lz,0);
    LZ.Free;

    _CompressedData.Seek(0,0);

    _unCompressedData.Seek(0,0);
   // _unCompressedData.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'Decompress.bmp');
    _unCompressedData.Seek(0,0);
    //freeandNIl(_CompressedData);
    _CompressedData.Free;
    _CompressedData:=NIL;

end;
constructor TWadItem.create;
begin
      self._UncompressedData:=nil;
      self._CompressedData:=nil;
end;

function TWadItem.CreateBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
    result:=TBitmap.Create;
    self.ReadToBitmap(result);
end;

function TWadItem.CurrentlyCompressed: Boolean;
begin
      result:=false;
      if self._CompressedData<>nil then result:=true;
      if self._UncompressedData<>nil then result:=False;

end;

destructor TWadItem.destroy;
begin
     try
        _UncompressedData.Free;
     except
            on exception do begin end;
     end;
     try
        _CompressedData.Free;
     except on exception do begin end;
     end;

end;

procedure TWadItem.AssignFromBitmap(FromBMP: TBitmap);
begin
      UnPack;
      if _UnCompressedData=nil then
      begin
        _UnCompressedData:=TMemoryStream.Create;
        _UnCompressedData.Clear;
      end;
      _UncompressedData.SetSize(0);
      _UnCompressedData.Seek(0,0);
      FromBMP.SaveToStream(_UnCompressedData);

end;
```

Comment: I've just uploaded the file WadLibraries.pas where all the example code came from to my sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlogprotection/files/Source/